# Understanding gnome-disk mount options

Tags: gnome, mount, disk-utility

I am using the `gnome-disk-utilities` UI to manage my auto-mounts. The problem is that I don't fully understand the mount options. Is there no way to directly set the default access privileges like with `chmod`?

The default seems to be `rwxrwxrwx`, which is what I get when setting mount options to:

```
gid=1000,uid=1000
```

How could I set the default mod of the mounting point (and possibly, its directories) to something else? E.g. `rwxrwx---`?